# Insert into database date with another format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a gridview and sqldatasource.

I'm trying to insert new records in database and the Date column type is Date and default format is US , mm/dd/yyyy and I'm trying to insert a date with another format.

```
  SqlDataSource2.InsertCommand = "Insert into test (Name,Date) VALUES (@Name,@CONVERT(Date,'@Date',104))";
        SqlDataSource2.InsertParameters.Add("Name", nameText);
        SqlDataSource2.InsertParameters.Add("Date", DbType.DateTime, date.Text);
```

I get: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Thanks

Comment: `date` (and `datetime`, `datetime2`, etc) columns don't *have* a format. They just store dates (and times). Convert your string into a `DateTime` before you add it as a parameter, and let ADO.NET and SQL Server deal with it.

Comment: yes..I did that but insertt won't accept the datetime value , do I need to convert it to string and add it?

Comment: *No*, you want to *avoid* treating this as a string.

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.Add(string, System.Data.DbType, string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: `date.Text` suggests to me that you're trying to give it a string, not a datetime.

Comment: Yes and I've tried Datetime dt = Convert.ToDatetime(date.text) and In parameters I relplaced data.text with dt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Date type in format agnostic in the database (unless you store it as a string).

You may first try to get a valid `System.DateTime` object using `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.Parse`.

Then, set the SqlParameter with this value.

```
DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Parse(date.Text); // try to make this working first.
SqlDataSource2.InsertCommand= "Insert into test (Name,Date) VALUES (@Name,@Date)";
    SqlDataSource2.InsertParameters.Add("Name", nameText);
    SqlDataSource2.InsertParameters.Add("Date", DbType.DateTime, dateValue);
```

Comment: Ups my bad...I used Selectcommand instead of Insert command :D

Comment: The advise to prepare correct object types at the application level is still valid. It will far more maintainable, and let the db driver doing what it is build for.

Answer (score 2):

First you should use `DateTime` object instead of `Date.Text`, First convert your text into `DateTime`

Second you don't need to format date time while inserting if the data type is datatime at SQLServer table just use.

```
"Insert into test (Name,Date) VALUES (@Name, @Date)";
```

You should format date time while retrieving data in `select`

Comment: yes but it won't insert for example 30/02/2012 since it only allows mm/dd/yyyy