# Insert DateTime into Database #2

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, datetime

I am currently having problem to insert dateTime value into database. First, I choose a date from the calendar control in visual studio 2010. Then I formatted the date into dd/M/yyyy format. Here is the code:

```
protected void calendar_selectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tb_date.Text = calendar.SelectedDate.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        calendar.Visible = false;
    }
```

After that, I passed the user inputs to businessLogicLayer:

```
PackingBLL packing = new PackingBLL();
        string msg = "";
        msg = packing.createSession(tb_location.Text, tb_date.Text, tb_volunteerNeeded.Text);
        lbl_msg.Text = msg;
```

In my business logic layer:

```
public string createSession(string location, string dateStr, string volunteerNeededStr)
    {
        string returnMessage = "";

        if (returnMessage.Length == 0)
        {
            DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr, "dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            int volunteerNeeded = int.Parse(volunteerNeededStr);

            Packing packing = new Packing(location, date, volunteerNeeded);

            int nofRows = 0;
            nofRows = packing.PackingInsert();

            if (nofRows > 0)
                returnMessage = "Packing session record saved successfully.";
            else
                returnMessage = "Error! Please try again.";
        }

        return returnMessage;
    }
```

Then from there, I passed them into Data Access Layer to execute the Sql statement:

```
public static int executeNonQuery(string query)
    {
        int result = 0;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("FFTHDb executeNonQuery: " + query);

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        connection.Open();
        result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();

        return result;
    }

private DateTime _date;

    public DateTime date
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set { _date = value; }
    }

public int PackingInsert()
    {
        int nofRows = 0;
        nofRows = FFTHDb.executeNonQuery("INSERT INTO PackingSession (packingDate, packingLocation, volunteerNeeded) " + 
            " VALUES ('" + date + "' , '" + location + "' , " + volunteerNeeded + "");

        return nofRows;
    }
```

However, when I try to insert data, it keeps prompting me there's syntax error at line 10. But I have no idea on what went wrong with the Sql statement.

Comment: What's the data type of `packingDate` in the database?

Comment: I set it as DateTime. But I realized there is something wrong with my volunteerNeed. Becuase when I typed 12, the error message prompts me that there is syntax error at '12'. But when I typed 10, it prompts me for '10'.

Comment: And another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046614/insert-into-database-date-with-another-format/11046658#11046658

Comment: Thank for the effort to find related threads.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax error is the missing closing parentheses in the query. The `VALUES` statement is missing the closing parenthesis.

Another possible problem is the format of the date in the query. As you are concatenating a `DateTime` value into the query, the `ToString` method will be used to turn it into a string, which means that it will use the current culture (whatever that might be) to do the conversion. That might not be a date format that the database recognises, or it may be misinterpreted (e.g. `mm/dd/yyyy` instead of `dd/mm/yyyy`).

You should use a parameterised query, so that you send the parameters as their data type, not concatenate them into the query.

Side note: You should dispose the connection and command objects that you are using. The `using` keyword is good for that.

Example:

```
string query =
  "INSERT INTO PackingSession (packingDate, packingLocation, volunteerNeeded) " + 
  "VALUES (@Date, @Location, @VolunteerNeeded)";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection)) {
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", location);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VolunteerNeeded", volunteerNeeded);
    connection.Open();
    result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh ya, I left out with one closing bracket. But now the error turned to dateTime value out of range. Would you mind to show me some examples?

Comment: @Gwen: That would be because the date is misinterpreted, for example into 13-12-0014, which would be outside the range that a `datetime` can handle. I added an exampe with parameters above.

Comment: It works now. So basically from my previous code, I inserted the date as string because I put it as '" + date + "' ?

Comment: @Gwen: Yes, that has the same effect as `..." + date.ToString() + "...`.